# What does a job posting that mentions "relocation offered" mean?

Tags: job-search, relocation, benefits

Recently I have come across a lot of job postings that are marked as "relocation offered". I wonder that for those that don't have "Relocation Offered", does that mean that they won't accept applications from outside the country?

What exactly does it mean if a job position offers relocation?

Comment: This question is about a specific job opening.

Comment: Not really, it is in general as I am confused about the work permit and all

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unanswerable.

Comment: I disagree that it is off-topic. This is a great discussion - it is implied that "relocation" is defined but really it is not, a debate on what is understood is appropriate

Comment: "...for those that don't have "Relocation Offered", does that mean that they won't accept applications from outside the country?" - Who knows? How can we definitively answer that?

Comment: Within the US, it means that your new employer will move you from (for example) Cincinnati to San Jose. Moving you from another country is a bit trickier, however if you're qualified it may be worth it.  Bringing in a citizen of another country means sponsorship, and you will need to keep your job to be able to remain in the country (generally true for English speaking countries and Europe). If the relocation is into the US, it will take some time.

Comment: International relocation help is pretty big. They'd have to absorb a lot of the cost when they could hire someone in country with a predictable cost estimation. Best to call the company and tell them you are outside of the country looking to move into the US.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Offering relocation assistance and hiring people who don't live in the area are two different concerns.

Typically, job postings that offer relocation are offering relocation assistance. Often, this is some kind of compensation to cover moving expenses, finding a place to live in the new job location, and other things associated with getting from your current location to the location of the job. The kind of assistance varies by company, and could range from most or all expenses paid, to a sliding scale based on relocation distance, to a flat rate to offset some of your costs.

Accepting applicants from outside the country is a different matter and depends on the company. If you aren't a US citizen, there are companies that can not hire you due to the nature of the work. Others can, but choose not to sponsor the applicant for the required documentation for whatever reason. Typically, if a company requires US citizenship (or some other legal status), that's noted in the job posting. Companies that can may also note that they will sponsor the applicant for the required documents in the job posting. If neither are mentioned, it may be wise to contact the recruiter or HR department before getting too involved in the process.

Comment: That's more or less it. I'd add that one should be cautious when relocating because companies may offer relocation compensation that does not take effect until you have worked for them for a certain period of time.

Comment: More likely, they will pay you (because they can afford it and you can't) but the contract says that you have to pay something back if you leave within a year or two.

Comment: @gnasher729 is right. It's important to understand the "Terms" of the assistance.  I took a job with that program, once.  It was very straightforward.  I was allotted up to a certain amount for moving expenses.  I just turned in an expense report in my first week, and that was it. (I used about 60% of the allotment).  Every company's policy will be different, so get that policy in writing up front.

Comment: This answer is written from a US perspective.